# ExpandableListView doesn't scroll if at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, expandablelistview

I have an Android app with an `Activity`, with an `ExpanableListView` inside it.

What I want is for the `ExpandableListView` to scroll the chosen group's header, when I tap on it, and if it can't (because there isn't enough vertical space), I want it to scroll to the bottom.

If I tap on a group when the list view has more space at the bottom (i.e: other groups), everything works as it should, and the list view scrolls to show the children.
(Edit: No it doesn't; it only works properly for the first tap, all successive tries result in no scrolling)

However, if the list view has no space, no scrolling happens, the group expands, and I can then scroll further down to see the groups children.

I've tried a bunch of things, such as overriding '`onGroupClick`' and calling '`smoothScrollToPosition`', but the results are pretty much the same.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Put your layout xml file

Comment: post some code so that we can check and and provide further help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the below. Works perfectly:

```
public static class LineupFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;
ExpandableListView lv;
private String[] groups;
private String[][] children;


public LineupFragment() {

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    groups = new String[] { "Test Header 1", "Test Header 2", "Test Header 3", "Test Header 4" };

    children = new String [][] {
        { "s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." },
        { "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of comes from a line in section 1.10.32." },
        { "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)." },
        { "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc." }
    };
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lineup, container, false);  

return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    lv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    lv.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(groups, children));
    lv.setGroupIndicator(null);

}

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inf;
    private String[] groups;
    private String[][] children;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
        inf = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}
```